# How to add value to var when clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
function maintenance_text(e) {

var toop = 0;

    $('body')

    .before('<div class="maintenance_text" style="position: relative; top: '+toop+'px; left: 0px; right: 0px; z-index: 999999; background: black; color: white; font-size: 16px; cursor: default;">'+e+'</div>')

    .before(function() {

        $('.maintenance_text')
        .delay(3000)
        .fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });

    });

};
```

and this code for work:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript: maintenance_text('TEST'); return false;">Click here...</a>
```

and all works great, but I want get this effect when this div is fixed (not relative). But when it is fixed, then all "messages" is on one position and I want get every message under prev message, like on relative position.

I trying add toop var and add 10px every when function are run, but I do not know what to do it.

Relative teest:
http://jsfiddle.net/IdolwSzutrab7/9zJvL/4/

---

Edit: and I want to reset the toop position when all mesages disappear, exactly the same as when this div is relative.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to create a `fixed` wrapper around `maintenance_text`.  Then add each new div to it with relative positioning.

Updated HTML

```
<div id="wrapper" style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<a href="#" onclick="javascript: maintenance_text('TEST'); return false;">Click here...</a>
```

Updated JavaScript

```
$('#wrapper').before('<div class="maintenance_text" style="position: relative; top: '+toop+'px; left: 0px; right: 0px; z-index: 999999; background: black; color: white; font-size: 16px; cursor: default;">'+e+'</div>')
```

Here's an updated jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/9zJvL/7/

Comment: ohh... hmm... I test it now, wait a minute.

Comment: But then #wrapper is after body. I want create it before body, on the top of code. I add #wrapper to script bu't does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/IdolwSzutrab7/9zJvL/8/

Comment: Sorry, I updated my jsfiddle after I originally posted it.  Try the updated link I put.  In that one, I add the wrapper div manually in the HTML and then each `maintenance_text` div is that added to that.

Comment: You do not understand. You see the "Click here" text? In relative this text every time is go to bottom when you click "Click here". I want this all in fixed position to prevent this situation.

Comment: Then you should put the "Click here" link above the div.  If you're adding content to a div, and you want it to grow, anything below it will be pushed down the page.  Otherwise you could set the position of the link to absolute and place it where you want, but it will appear on top of lines you may add.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/o727zwzf/

Html

```
<div class="msg-container">
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<a href="#" onclick="javascript: maintenance_text('TEST'); return false;">Click here...</a>
<div style="height:500px">
for other content
</div>
```

js

```
  function maintenance_text(e) {
    $('.msg-container')

    .append('<div class="maintenance_text" style="left: 0px; right: 0px; background: black; color: white; font-size: 16px; cursor: default;">'+e+'</div>')

    .before(function() {

        $('.maintenance_text')
        .delay(3000)
        .fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });

    });

};
```

css

```
.maintenance_text{
    position:relative;
}

.msg-container{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's something that does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/9x0uau8s/

It uses the height of the other `.maintenance_text` elements to determine where its position should be. And when you remove an element, it adjusts the position of all elements after it by its height.

For instance...

```
var toop = 0; // Adding the element
$('.maintenance_text').map(function(i,e){toop+=$(e).height()});
$('<div>').addClass('maintenance_text').css({
    position: 'fixed',
    top: toop+'px'
}).fadeOut(function() { // Removing the element
    var t = $(this);
    t.nextAll('.maintenance_text').map(function(i,e){
        var o = $(e).offset();
        o.top=o.top-t.height();
        $(e).offset(o);
    });
    t.remove();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok I did it myself, here is working code for test:
http://jsfiddle.net/IdolwSzutrab7/9zJvL/

```
function maintenance_text(e, color) {

if (color == 'red') {
    color = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)'
} else if (color == 'blue') {
    color = 'rgba(0, 102, 255, 0.5)'
} else {
    color = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)'
};

    $('body')

    .append('<div id="maintenance_wrapper"></div>')

    .find('#maintenance_wrapper')

    .css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': '0px',
        'left': '0px',
        'right': '0px',
        'z-index': '999999'

     })

    .append('<div class="maintenance_text" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; background:'+color+'; padding: 3px; color: white; font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial; cursor: default; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;">'+e+'</div>')

    .after(function() {

        $('.maintenance_text')
        .delay(3000)
        .fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });

    });

};
```

After all I decided to add this code after body, using append. And also I added colors.

Thx all for helping!